# Gitlab CE: configure 1 Gitlab for 3 Domains w/ different groups&projects, but 1 login?

Tags: gitlab, multisite

Here's what I'd like to do:

- Install Gitlab CE
- Point 3 toplevel domains to it (domain.fr, domain.it, domain.es)
- Groups, Projects and Issues are filtered per TLD (group 1-6 on .fr, group 7-10 on .it)
- User can login on all 3 platforms
- User dashboard displays groups and projects from all TLDs

Does anyone know of such a config?